# PydanticUserError('`const` is removed, use `Literal` instead', code='removed-kwargs')

Tags: python, pydantic

I am using the datamodel-code-generator to generate my pydantic model class.
Here is my schema:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "title": "Name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "status": {
      "const": "active",
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "name",
    "status"
  ],
  "title": "MyBaseModel",
  "type": "object"
}
```

and this generates a class:

```
from __future__ import annotations

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class MyBaseModel(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(..., title='Name')
    status: str = Field('active', const=True)
```

But while importing this class, I am getting

```
 raise PydanticUserError('`const` is removed, use `Literal` instead', code='removed-kwargs')
pydantic.errors.PydanticUserError: `const` is removed, use `Literal` instead
```

How can I specify in my json schema to generate pydantic classes with literal?
Using versions:
`Pydantic:2.0.3`
`datamodel-code-generator:0.22.0`

Answer (score 0):

2 things to fix this:

- Use enum in your json schema eg:

```
"status": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["active"]
      },
```

- Use `--enum-field-as-literal {all,one}` during code generation.
  Ref: https://pypi.org/project/improved-datamodel-codegen/